# HTML element is not becoming an automatic positioning context

Tags: css

Compare these two examples, the only difference being whether the `html` element is given `position: relative`.

- http://jsfiddle.net/3bNE5/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/3bNE5/3/

As I understand the CSS spec, if there is no non-`position: static` parent, the html element is supposed to become that parent.  In this case though, it seems like somehow the viewport (or the containing iframe?) is becoming the parent.  What's going on?

This is the entire example from the jsfiddle for posterity:

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}

div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 spec defines the initial containing block as 'For continuous media, it has the dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin;'

Lacking a positioning context, that containing block is becoming the context.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html

Comment: That's most definitely the CSS2 spec - it says so in the URL. The CSS3 spec is located elsewhere altogether. Also, CSS does not define the term "positioning context" anywhere - there's just "containing block".